# Tabela dentro da View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou colocando uma tabela dentro da view de Edit.

View de Edit (Contrato)

```
@if (Model.ContratoParcela.Any())
{
    <table class="table parcela-lista">
        @foreach (var parcela in Model.ContratoParcela)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href="#" data-contratoid="@parcela.id_Contrato" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalParcelaEdit">@parcela.valor</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Porém o @if ficam em vermelhos, sublinhados.

Quero pegar as informações da tabela ContratoParcela e exibir na view de Edit que vem da tabela Contrato.

Tomo esse erro:

> Unexpected "if" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "if" with "@".

Comment: Tira o @ da frente do if.

Comment: Era isso mesmo? Só tirar o **@**, Marcos?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente você já está dentro de um bloco de coberto pelo @.
Você pode:
Estar numa situação assim:

```
@{
  if(true) { }
}
```

Ou assim:

```
@if(true) {
  if (true) { }
}
```

em ambos os casos você já possui um @ em volta do if, então não será necessário colocar outro.